# Order of operations Incorrect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm using the Python 3.5.2 shell. I am confused about why this works as it does?

```
5 > 5**2
False
5 > 5**2 == False
False
(5 > 5**2) == False
True
```

The order of the operations defines that ** is executed before > which is before == so it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question! The reason for this behavior is that all the comparison operators in Python have equal precedence and *[can be chained](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)*.

So your second comparison is equivalent to

`5 > 25 and 25 == False`

which of course evaluates to `False`.
But I agree that in this case, it's not very intuitive.

Comment: You can always use parentheses to override this chaining: `(5 > 5**2) == False` => `True`

Comment: @brianpck True, but why would you ever want that? Comparisons will always yield a boolean (unless overloaded in a very unorthodox way), and comparing a boolean to e.g. True or False is bad practice in the first place. Instead of `(5 > 5**2) == False`, just do `not (5 > 5**2)`, or `5 <= 5**2`

Comment: @tobias_k, granted, but the premise of the OP (I hope!) was experimentation, not actual problem-solving. I've written *much* weirder code just to get a handle on language features.

Comment: @tobias_k, you don't need it often, but sometimes you want an XOR or XNOR of two comparisons.  For example, in verifying the invariant of a sorted array, `if (i <= j) != (a[i] <= a[j])` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

5.15. Operator precedence

The following table summarizes the operator precedences in Python, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding). Operators in the same box have the same precedence. Unless the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary. Operators in the same box group left to right (except for comparisons, including tests, which all have the same precedence and chain from left to right — **see section Comparisons — and exponentiation, which groups from right to left**).

[5 Expressions - Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)